# Append prefix to first column of a file with awk

Tags: awk, gawk

I have a couple of hundreds of files which I want to process with xargs. They all need a fix of their first column.

Therefore I need an awk command to append the prefix "ID_" to the first column of a file (except for the first header line). Can anyone help me with this?

Something along the line:

```
gawk -f ';' "{$1='ID_' $1; print $0}" file.csv > file_processed.csv
```

I am not expert for the command, though. And I would rather like to have some inplace processing instead of making a copy of each file. Beforehand, I made it in VIM, but then I only had one file.

```
:%s/^-/ID_/
```

I hope someone can help me here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
gawk 'BEGIN{FS=";"; OFS=";"} {if(NR>1) $1="ID_"$1; print}' file.csv > file_processed.csv
```

`FS` and `OFS` set the input and output field separators, respectively.

`NR>1` checks whether current line number is larger than 1, so we don't modify the header line.

You can also modify the file in place with `-i inplace` option:

```
gawk -i inplace 'BEGIN{FS=";"; OFS=";"} {if(NR>1) $1="ID_"$1; print}' file.csv
```

**Edit**

After elaborating the original question, here's the final version:

```
gawk -i inplace 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} NR>1{sub(/^-/,"ID_",$2)} 1' file.csv
```

which substitutes `-` in the beginning of second column with `ID_`.
`NR>1` action applies for all but first (header) line. `1` invokes the default default print action.

Comment: It turns out that I need to make a substitute operation "-" into "ID_" for the prefix of the column values, and that the target of that operation is the second rather than the first column:

Comment: I am trying `gawk -i inplace 'BEGIN{FS=";"; OFS=";"} {if(NR>1) $2=gsub("^-", "ID_", $2); print}' file.csv` but it's not working as intended.

Comment: `[g]sub()` modifies variable in place, so you don't need assignment, thus: `{if(NR>1) sub(/^-/, "ID_", $2); print}`

Comment: More awkishly - `'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} NR>1{$1="ID_"$1} 1'` but realistically you probably only need `'NR>1{$0="ID_"$0} 1'`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to do something, particularly adding a prefix, on the first field, it is not different from adding the prefix to the whole line.

So you can just `awk '$0 = "ID_" $0' file.csv` it should do the work. If you want to make it "change in place", you can:

```
awk '$0="ID_"$0' csv >/tmp/foo && mv /tmp/foo file.csv
```

You can also make use of `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/^/ID_/' file
```

The `-i` does "in-place modification"

You mentioned `vim`, and gave `s/^-/ID_/` cmd, it doesn't **add** the prefix (`ID_`), it will **replace** the leading `-` by the `ID_`, they are different.

Comment: You are right. It's my mistake. I actually need to execute the VIM substitution command now on many files. So, it is indeed a substituting of the leading "-", not a mere concatenation. Sorry for the confusion, and many thanks for your help!